# Basis representation

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Let $u_1,\ldots,u_d$ be an orthonormal basis. It is given that $|u_i^Te_1| \leq \epsilon$ for all $i =2,\dots,d$ where $\epsilon$ is a small number. That is each such $u_i$ is roughly perpendicular to $e_1$. Now given a vector $v$ perpendicular to $e_1$ can we show that $v$ as a linear combination of $u_1, \dots, u_d$, the components of $v$ is mostly concentrated on $u_2,\dots,u_d$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If fact as all $u_i$ are approximately perpendicular to $e_1$, we get the $e_1$ and $u_1$ must be pretty much dependent, as:
$$ e_1 = \sum_i \langle e_1,u_i\rangle u_i = \langle e_1,u_1\rangle u_1 + R $$
with $||R|| \leq (d-1)\epsilon$ and $R$ orthogonal to $u_1$ (and thus $f=\langle e_1,u_1\rangle$ close to $1$ if $\epsilon$ is small enough).

But thus if $v$ is perpendicular to $e_1$ then
$$\langle v,u_1\rangle = \langle v, e_1/f\rangle - \langle v,R/f\rangle=- \langle v,R/f\rangle$$
As $f\approx1$ we have $1/f\approx1$, and as $||R||$ small we get
$$ |\langle v,u_1\rangle| \approx |\langle v,R\rangle| \leq ||v||(d-1)\epsilon$$
This means that as long as $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small, the mass of $v$ will be concentrated on $u_2,\ldots,u_d$.